# Existence of an element in a subgroup

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and $H$ a subgroup of $G$.

In a previous part I have proved that if we have an element $x\in G$ such that $x$ has order $d$, and $r$ being the least positive integer such that $x^r\in H$, then $r\mid d$.

The next part says: Suppose further that $H$ has index $n$. If $x\in G$, show that $x^k \in H$ for some $k$ such that $0<k\leq n$. Is it always the case that the least positive such $k$ is a factor of $n$?

I am currently on the first statement. What I want to prove is that if $r$ is the least positive integer such that $x^r \in H$, then $0<r\leq n$. I know that $r \mid d$, and so $r\leq d$, and also that $d\vert |G| = n|H|$, but this is not enough to tell me that $d\leq n$.

Am I along the right lines?

Comment: For the first part, consider the cosets $H$, $xH$, $x^2H,\ldots, x^nH$. For the second, consider a subgroup of index $3$ in $S_3$ to answer the question asked.

Comment: I can't think of a way to show $d\leq n$ that doesn't use stuff much harder than just looking at the cosets...